# Required String parameter 'newPassword' is not present

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, axios

**SOLVED**

We've solved it. The form that the backend requires data was param, so the form that the vue sends was changed to param, not data!

---

I'm making a password change page.
Meanwhile, I got an error that there was no old password, new password data but I definitely transferred the data from Vue through axios.

There were answers to 'required=false', so I tried oldpassword, but here's the result.

[image]

[image]

However, we took 'required= true' because we believe newpassword, oldpassword is essential data for this approach.
When using post-man or swagger, the password is changed signaling 200 normally.

I thought there might be a problem with 'patch', so I tried 'put', but the error didn't change.

**frontend**

```html
<div class="input-with-label">
    <input v-model="newpassword" id="newpassword" placeholder="새 비밀번호를 입력하세요." :type="passwordType"  />
    <label for="newpassword">새 비밀번호</label>
    <div class="error-text" v-if="error.newpassword">{{error.newpassword}}</div>
</div>

<form @submit.prevent="changepassword" @submit="checkForm">
    <div v-if="activeButton() && !isSubmit">
        <!-- <button @click="PopUpEmailModal" class="btn-bottom" >가입하기</button> -->
        <button class="btn-bottom">변경하기</button>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
        <button class="btn-bottom disabled" >변경하기</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

```js
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  name:'ChangePassword',
  data: ()=> {
    return{
      email:"",
      oldpassword:"",
      newpassword:"",
      isSubmit: true,
      error: {
        newpassword: false,
      },
      passwordType: "password",
      passwordSchema: new PV(),
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.passwordSchema
      .is()
      .min(8)
      .is()
      .max(100)
      .has()
      .digits()
      .has()
      .letters();
  },
  watch: {
    newpassword: function(v) {
      this.checkForm();
    },
  },
  methods:{
    changepassword(){
        axios({
          url:'http://127.0.0.1:8080/account/changePassword',
          method:'patch',
          data:{
            email: this.email,
            oldPassword: this.oldpassword,
            newPassword: this.newpassword,
          },
        })
          .then(res=>{
            console.log(res)
            this.$router.push({ name:'Login' })
          })
          .catch(err=>{
            console.log(typeof this.oldpassword)
            console.log(this.oldpassword)
            console.log(this.newpassword)
            console.log(this.email)
            console.log(err)
          })
    },
  }
```

**backend**

```java
@PatchMapping("/account/changePassword")
    @ApiOperation(value = "비밀번호변경")
    public Object changePassword(@RequestParam(required = false) final String oldPassword,
                                 @RequestParam(required = true) final String newPassword,
                                 @RequestParam(required = true) final String email){
        Optional<User> userOpt = userDao.findByEmail(email);
        if(!passwordEncoder.matches(oldPassword, userOpt.get().getPassword())){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("잘못된 비밀번호입니다.");
        }
        User user = new User(userOpt.get().getUid(), userOpt.get().getNickname(), email,
                passwordEncoder.encode(newPassword), userOpt.get().getIntroduction(), userOpt.get().getThumbnail(), userOpt.get().getRoles());
        userDao.save(user);
        final BasicResponse result = new BasicResponse();
        result.status = true;
        result.data = "success";
        ResponseEntity response = null;
        response = new ResponseEntity<>("OK", HttpStatus.OK);
        return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are using @RequestParam annotations but you are not sending any params in the URL from the frontend, hence the 400 error.

Since you are using Patch/Put I would suggest you change your changePassword function to take a dto. And since you are already sending data in the body from frontend so no change needed there.

For example

```
public Object changePassword(@RequestBody @Valid ChangePasswordDto changePasswordDto){
// your logic 
}
```

Then create a `ChangePasswordDto` class with `@Required` on properties that are required.

```
public class ChangePasswordDto{
 
    private String email;    
    private String newPassword;
    private String oldPassword;
    
    @Required
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email= email;
    }

    @Required
    public void setOldPassword(String oldPassword) {
        this.oldPassword= oldPassword;
    }
    @Required
    public void setNewPassword(String newPassword) {
        this.newPassword= newPassword;
    }

    // corresponding getters
}
```

Comment: We've solved it.
The form that the backend requires data was param, so the form that the vue sends was changed to pm, not data!